# Do unrelated keywords in the careers bar and footer hurt Googlers, and can we fix it by not serving them to the Googlebot?

Tags: discussion, search, google

Recently a junior colleague of mine started working on a project with Drupal. Nobody in our shop has used Drupal before, and so he frequently hits Google for debugging help. A typical Google search might look like

```
drupal "some php or mysql error message i just got"
```

Today I was trying to lend a hand debugging some issues he couldn't get his head around, and was struck by the number of non-Drupal-related Stack Overflow results I got for Google searches that began with the word *drupal*. My colleague has also complained to me that when searching for help with some error he's encountered *in the context of Drupal development*, he'll often get Stack Overflow results from non-Drupal contexts before he gets to better, Drupal-related content. Searching for [*drupal collations*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=drupal%20collations), for example, gives me a [Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367711/what-is-the-best-collation-to-use-for-mysql-with-php) about MySQL collations with no Drupal context at all on the front page.

It took a while for it to occur to me that the problem might be stuffing of irrelevant keywords via the footer. After all, from Google's perspective, isn't every single page on Stack Overflow at least a little bit Drupal-related?

[image: image showing the SO footer, including a link to Drupal Answers]

I don't have any data to back up this idea - only a vague hunch - so I ask more SEO-literate users to forgive me if my hunch is nonsense. But is it? And if not, does the careers sidebar (which may similarly be full of deceptive keywords) contribute to the same effect? And if Stack Overflow were to stop serving the footer and careers pane to the Googlebot, would it help Googlers get more relevant results and boost the SEO of the smaller computing- or development-related Stack Exchange sites whose keywords [SO](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/) [is](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) [stuffing](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) [into](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) [every](https://security.stackexchange.com/) [page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) [via](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) [the](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) [footer](https://askubuntu.com/)?

Comment: That particular search is including the Drupal in a linked question.  In theory linked questions do provide some information - assuming the linking is good - because maybe a drupal person has an error that's mysql related.  I would think a [tag:drupal] question would get priority over this (I'm fairly sure the tags are the #1 thing that Google considers in ranking SO pages).

Comment: FWIW *Googler* is generally used to refer to a Google employee, not someone using Google's search service.

Comment: @WilliamShakespeare One would think that should be Googlee...

Comment: I think *Googler* is commonly used for a searcher.  UrbanDictionary for example includes both meanings.

Comment: I came here from the "Hot Meta Posts" sidebox, which shortened this question to *"Does serving the careers bar and footer to the Googlebot hurt Googlers by ass…"*, making it seem a lot more interesting than it actually turned out to be.

Comment: @Blazemonger I read it like "hurt Google in the ass" the first time, and thought "wtf, does Google have a similar careers ad-service and they're out-competing it"?

Answer (score 4):

I think the thing is that, in your colleague's case, the Googlebot considers any page that mentions Drupal more relevant than one that does not.  The Googlebot just can't tell the difference between a relevant Drupal page and an irrelevant one.  I suggest that your colleague use Google's own search feedback form to tell them that the search engine isn't exactly helping him find relevant answers.

Comment: *"The Googlebot just can't tell the difference between a relevant Drupal page and an irrelevant one."* This misses the point of the question - that we can probably help the Googlebot along by *not serving it* misleading content. Just sniff for its user agent, and when you see it, don't serve the site footer or the careers section. It will end up with strictly more relevant content to index without affecting anyone else's usage of the site.

Comment: @MarkAmery that's not good to sniff the user agent as this can penalize you (Google always knows :D). I'm curious if a nofollow attribute would make the link text not indexed, either.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin do you have any evidence to back up the suggestion that Google might penalize a site for serving different content to the Googlebot?

Comment: @MarkAmery take it from Google directly: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en

Comment: What if, instead of having a Drupal site, we just had a site dedicated to content management systems like Drupal? We could throw WordPress and Blogger into the site, too.

Comment: Google doesn't list "excluding navigation or other boilerplate" as an example of abuse. They do state categorically that *any* difference is abuse, but I bet they don't really mean it, so I don't think that link is conclusive. For example I don't think http://myhttp.info/ is abusive even though it shows different content according to user-agent, and any Google preview would be misleading ;-). Tbh I'm disappointed that Google doesn't identify site-wide boilerplate and consider it irrelevant to the specific page.

Comment: Yay, http://duckduckgo.com works better.

Answer (score 1):

Just about every web page on the entire interweb has some amount of decorative material on it. Ads, nav bars, <del>fnords</del>, you name it. Google (and competitors) didn't get to be Google (and competitors) by being stupid about this. Madame Google can tell. In fact, to avoid various SEO scams, Madame Google and her fellow search engines are extremely skeptical of miscellaneous words far away from paragraphs of actual text.

Answer (score 0):

That can only happen on questions for which google cannot find appropriate links. I use google for years (and discovered SO this way ...). I seldom found pages totally unrelated to the question I asked (words in pubs around the page), but admitted it was inherent to any search engine.

I never really blamed neither Google nor the site, because generaly Google's algorythme put good pages (notably SO ones :-) ) on top. And when it happens, I think it is a good use case for asking the question in SO (provided it is a relevant question) saying *Searched google for that and found nothing ...*